# PHP Combining search function with pagination

Tags: php, search, pagination

So I'm trying to make a page where i can display results from my database table. You should be able to search and there should be some pagination as there are thousands of results.

I've managed to make a page which just has the search, and works perfect. So now i need to know how would would integrate some pagination into that.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="container">
        <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
        <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        <?php include 'process.php'; ?>
      </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php include 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php   
$search = $_GET['search'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oantkb WHERE Name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY `INDEX` DESC");

echo '<table class="table">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>#</th>';
echo '<th>Pic</th>';
echo '<th>Name</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $pic = $row['Pic'];
    $name = $row['Name'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>#</td>';
    echo '<td><img src="'.$pic.'" height="50" width 50"></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Right now it works like it should. When i search it will say index.php?search=banana, but i need some pagination added so it will say for example index.php?search=banana&?page=2. Or something along those lines. Hope it makes sense...i'm a php newb :)

Comment: Change your `$search` declaration to: `$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);` - help prevent sql injection by sanitizing your input. Or just use mysqli/pdo with variable binding.

Answer (score 1):

Include at the end of your sql query the following:

```
$resultsPerPage=10;
$page = ($_GET["page"]-1)*$resultsPerPage;
$query = $query." LIMIT $page,$resultsPerPage";
mysql_query($query);
```

By the way the mysql_ library is deprecated in favor of mysqli.

Also the above is susceptible to sql injection attacks because $_GET["page"] isn't first sanitized, but for simplicity I did it this way.

This assumes a paging scheme that starts at 1.

Answer (score 0):

i've been using Pear Pagination for a long time. you can try it.

here is a good tutorial for setting it up

[Simple Pagination in PHP tutorial](http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/)

a good thing to add is clean your variable before using them in your query.